# Upgrading RAM, will this chip mix ok?

Tags: memory

Thanks for taking a look. This is the RAM running on my notebook:

https://www.skhynix.com/products/computing/view.jsp?info.ramKind=20&info.serialNo=HMT425S6AFR6A

This is the one I am planning to buy:

[Corsair Value DDR3 4 GB 1600 MHZ Laptop Memory Ram](http://www.amazon.in/gp/product/B00BQ14GUC/ref=gno_cart_title_0?ie=UTF8&psc=1&smid=AVZW9QZ9BO8BU)

Won't it be compactable? Also is my selection a cheap one which will affect performance, even though the brand is good?

Edit: Also, I found out that this chip is 1.5v, but the other is 1.35v. I tried digging up more info about my mobo(hannstar j mv-6 94v-0), but could not find any. Should I look for another product?

Comment: http://superuser.com/search?tab=newest&q=DDR3L%20SODIMM & http://superuser.com/questions/916937/should-we-expect-ddr3l-ram-to-work-on-the-intel-first-gen-core-i3-platform?s=42|0.0000  Read these Q&As for more info, that is along the same lines.   You should aquire compatability information from either your manuel, or from the online site for the computer, because the memory compatability charts are full of specific modules tested to work (if you can get them , or very very close to the same).

Comment: Now, I've changed my mind and will be buying   [this one](http://www.kingston.com/datasheets/kvr16ls11_4.pdf) as it seems to have the exact specs and costs a bit lower!

Comment: Update your question, I hate these types of questions, but I will answer sit only if the question is 100% complete and exactly what your asking about.  Be specific exact part numbers, include the voltage and frequency of both modules in the question itself