# DDR3L SO-DIMM not crashing in 1.5V laptop but works in 1.3v one laptop?

Tags: memory, compatibility, memtest86+

My laptop is DDR3 (1.5v),

I have bought an DDR3L (1.3v) 4GB SO-DIMM and it is crashing in and MemTest86 right at very start ( other 2GB DDR3L (1.3v) it works fine in this laptop at 1.5v).

Perhaps faulty memory stick, however when i put that 4GB DDR3L (1.3v) into laptop that only supports DDR3L (1.3v) it functions normally no errors in MemTest86.

What does it tell about this 4GB DDR3L stick is on the verge of failing soon? Was it probably overclocked and got fried?

Comment: Can you provide your Brand and model of laptop and maybe CPU Specs, This is to add more details to your question. Please use the Edit button on your question to add those details.

Comment: @ human_rosas

Lenovo B560 is 1.5v
Dell Inspiron 14 3878 is 1.3v

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should we expect DDR3L RAM to work on the Intel first-gen Core i3 platform?](https://superuser.com/questions/916937/should-we-expect-ddr3l-ram-to-work-on-the-intel-first-gen-core-i3-platform)

Comment: @human_rosas I am running 2GB DDR3L (1.3v) RAM just fine in B560 laptop.